# Positioning UIImageView with setAutoresizingMask

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm updating my app for iPhone 5 screens. It sounds like setAutoresizingMask would be good to use for positioning objects (instead of hard coding alt coordinates), but I can't seem to get it to work.

My app does not rotate, I just want this image to load fixed to the bottom, for 480 or 568 high screens.

Here is my simple attempt. Would be very grateful for suggestions. Thanks.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

    UIImage *getImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"footer.jpg"];
    UIImageView *footer = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:getImg];
    [footer setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,302,50)];
    [footer setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];    

    [self.view addSubview:footer];
}
```

(I believe this setAutoresizingMask should set the image to the bottom-left.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autoresizing masks don't affect the control's initial position, they just affect how the position updates when their superview changes its bounds. Put another way, the act of setting a new autoresizing mask will never update the control's position.

As a result, you'll still need to take care to put the control in the right spot initially. You can do that with interface builder easily enough. If you're laying out your interface programmatically, you should place your control relative to the bounds of its superview by querying its `bounds` member variable, instead of hardcoding measurements directly. From that point on, you can leave updates to the autoresizing mask.

Comment: Oh, that is a bit disappointing. Never mind. Thanks for the info.

Comment: It's actually a good thing it works that way. It would be rarely useful if the masks were only good at setting one of 9 possible positions. This way lets you position elements however you like, then not worry about subsequent updates. It's much more flexible.